# do we need synchronization in close method, if we are using hashwheel timer which closes the channel

Tags: java, synchronization, netty

do we need synchronization in close method, if we are using hashwheel timer which closes the channel

I have a handler which is added into pipe line along with a hash wheeled timer which is passed to the handler, handler is created for every new connection from client.Timer is created in pipeline factory. my need is if the client doesn't do any activity for specified amount of time, the timer should close the channel. and in handler i have close method which is exceuted when close event is fired. so is there any need for synchronization on close method... as when close is called all callback handlers will be called... will it cause an deadlock....

Please suggest

Comment: Please show your code. At least fragment.

Comment: Thanks ALex for the reply, i can't share the code as it is proprietory,i can explain what has been done, i have a handler which is created for every client connection, but a timer object is passed as argument while creating the handler , the timer task is to close the channel if the client doesn't send updates in configured amount of time, handler has states open ,close etc in certain conditions close state is set and close channel method is called... the timer can also call the close channel method... do i need synchronization on close channel method... can deadlock happen if i synchronize

Comment: Show the code. Create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I have added the SSCCE , please have a look

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on quite a few things - hence the calls to see your code.

HashedWheelTimer always fires the timeout event on a background thread created using either the default Java thread factory, or a supplied thread factory. Unless you are taking specific action to control this then, if your TimerTask is being executed directly by HashedWheelTimer, it is highly likely to be on a separate thread and you should perform any synchronisation necessary.

If you are using Netty's ReadTimeoutHandler or IdleStateHandler the behaviour depends on which version of Netty you are using. Before Netty 3.5 the timeout was fired on the HashedWheelTimer thread and synchronisation may be necessary.

Since Netty 3.5 (including Netty 4.0) the timeout handlers queue the timeout event to the I/O worker thread to which the channel is assigned. This means the event is raised serially with all other channel events. Synchronisation should not be necessary.

If you are using Netty 3.5 or later I would urge you to consider using the timeout handlers provided as they are pretty easy to use. If using one of the supplied handlers is not an option you could queue the event to the I/O worker yourself. How you achieve this depends on the Netty version so I suggest looking at the source code to ReadTimeoutHandler to see how it's done.

Note the above assumes you have not added executors to your pipeline that do not preserve the order of channel events (eg MemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor in Netty 3.x).

Answer (score 0):

```
class DataStreamHandler extends IdleStateAwareChannelUpstreamHandler {
private final Timer timer;
private final Timer idleTimer;`enter code here`
private Channel channel;
private SslHandler sslhandler;
private String serverId;
private boolean certClientId = false;
public enum State {
 Open{ 
 protected boolean handle (DataStreamHandler dh, Message event) {
 //some logic to proceed to Established state handler
 //other wise closed state handler
  handler.write(event.getMessage(),),
                    State, null, true);
                    // write methods sets the state specified
} 
},
 Established{ protected boolean handle (DataStreamHandler dh, Message event) {
 //some logic some logic to proceed to Bind state handler
  handler.write(event.getMessage(),),
                    State, null, true);
                    // write methods sets the state specified other wise closed state handler
}  },
 Bind { protected boolean handle (DataStreamHandler dh, Message event) {
// some logic values below are configurable
channelPipeline.replace(idlestatehandler, new IdleStateHandler(this.idletimer, 10000,0,10000, milliseconds));
 handler.write(event.getMessage(),),              State, null, true);// write methods sets the state specified
}                   
} 
},
 Closed{ protected boolean handle (DataStreamHandler dh, Message event) {
//logic to set handler to fire closed event
} }
};
@Override
public void  channelConnected(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, final ChannelStateEvent e) {
synchronized(this) {
this.channel = ctx.getChannel();
this.sslHandler= ctx.getPipeline().get(SslHandler.class);
//set enum state to Established
}
super.channelConnected(ctx, e);     
}
@Override
public void messageReceived(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, final MessageEvent e) {
synchronized(this) {            
if (!this.setCertClientId && !setCertClientId()) {
return;
}
//before processing the message ssl handler is used
}
}
  private boolean setCertClientId() {
synchronized(this) {
this.setCertClientId = true;
if (this.sslHandler == null) {
return true;
}
//the ssl handler is added for every channel in getpipeline.
final SSLEngine sslEngine = sslHandler.getEngine(); 
//ssl related checks done other wise channel close is called
}
}
@Override
public void channelClosed(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx,
final ChannelStateEvent e)throws Exception { //NOSONAR, throw exception is from netty
synchronized(this) {
//set enum state to CLOSED
}
super.channelClosed(ctx, e);
}   
private void closeChannel() {
final SslHandler theSslHandler;
synchronized(this) { 
this.closePending = true;
theSslHandler =  this.sslHandler;
if (sslHandler == null) {
future = getChannel().close();
} else  {
future = theSslHandler.close();
}
  monitorCloseChannel(future);   // this methd has a listener to future 
  if(theSslHandler != null) {
    // the CloseTask is  a static class which impelemets the timer task to close the stream or the channel depending upon boolean value supplied
       this.timer.newTimeout(new CloseTask(this, true), this.closeTimeoutMs, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
       }
}
    super.channelClosed(ctx, e);
    }               

  @Override
    public void channelIdle(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, 
                            final IdleStateEvent e) throws Exception { //NOSONAR, throw exception is from netty
    synchronized(this) {
      switch (e.getState()) {
        case ALL_IDLE:
          if (this.closePending) { 
                   // close the channel directly
          } else { 
              this.closePending = true;
              //call the CloseTask class to close the channel or stream
          }
          break;
            case READER_IDLE:
                if (getState() == State.ESTABLISHED) {
                 //some logic
                }
          break;
         case WRITER_IDLE:

          break;
          }
         }
    super.channelIdle(ctx, e);
}               

 @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, 
                                             final ExceptionEvent e)
            throws Exception {    
     if (!this.closePending) {

        if (//checked for various exceptions) {
          //call
        closeChannel();
        } else {

         // call the CloseTask timertask class to close the channel or stream
                }
         } else {

                log.debug("Received exception while closing", e.getCause());
}
} 
}       
protected abstract boolean handle (DataStreamHandler dh, Message event);
public DataStreamHandler () {
this.timer = timer;
this.idleTimer= idleTimer;
this.channel= channel;
this.sslhandler=sslhandler;
this.serverId=serverId;
}
}
```

Comment: This is the sample skeleton code being used,  flow is as follows the client establishes a persistent connection in bind state.sends periodic  updates to server, in message recieved method, we check for ssl related checks if it fails and channel is closed(sslhandler is added for every channel). if any message is not proper or stream error or in case of any exception channel will be closed... in close  , idle , messagerecieved,exceptioncaught method do i need synchronization as it can be called by the idlestatehandler's channelIdle method if connection is idle , . netty being used is 3.2.5